# Eclipse 2023-03 does not provide accurate code assist hints for lines like "Set set = hew HashSet();"

Tags: java, eclipse

Environment:

1. Linux Fedora 37 and MacOS on 2023 MacBook Pro M2.
2. Oracle Java 17 (17.0.7 on Fedora, 17.0.6 on Mac).
3. Eclipse 2023-03 on both Fedora and Mac.

Recently moved from Eclipse 2022-09 to 2023-03. After doing so, noticed that "code assist" had problems on both Fedora and Mac. What follows is a simple example that illustrates the problem. Start with a brand new empty workspace. Add a new project; uncheck the "Create module-info.java file" box. Add the following code to the default package. Text continues following code.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
//      Set s1 =
//      Set s2 = new HashSet();
//      HashSet hs1 =
//      HashSet hs2 = new HashSet();
    }
}
```

Classic "hello world" program. Note the 4 commented lines.

1. Uncomment the first one. Red squiggly line appears under "Set".
2. Hover your mouse on Set. Note the dropdown hints. States that "Set cannot be resolved to a type". Provides 12 quick fixes, the top one being "Import 'Set' (java.util)". This is the correct fix. DO NOT CHOOSE IT. Instead, re-comment the line. If you did choose the fix, then also delete the added include line.
3. Uncomment the second commented line. Red squiggly lines appear under "Set" and "HashSet". Hover on Set. Note the dropdown hints. States that "Set cannot be resolved to a type". Provides 6 quick fixes. The correct fix -- "Import 'Set' (java.util)" -- is not there!!!??? Same thing when hovering on HashSet. Re-comment the line.
4. Uncomment the third commented line. Similar behavior as in 2. In particular, the correct fix is at the top -- "Import 'HashSet' (java.util)". Re-comment the line.
5. Uncomment the fourth commented line. Similar behavior as in 3. Red squiggly lines on the two HashSet occurrences. Hovering on either does not show the correct fix. Re-comment the line.

I still have Eclipse 2022-09 so I decided to do the same tests there. Created a new workspace, new project without the module-info.java button checked, and created the same source. This time all steps work correctly. In particular, step 3 shows the correct fixes for Set and HashSet and step 5 shows the correct fixes for both occurrences of HashSet.

After doing the Eclipse 2022-09 test, I repeated the Eclipse 2023-03 test using the 2022-09 workspace. Same problem as described above occurred.

Summary. The correct code assist hints seem to be available in Eclipse 2023-03 (see 2 and 4), but not displayed in all cases (see 3 and 5). Occurs on both Fedora and Mac. Problem does not occur for Eclipse 2022-09.

Since this issue seems too easy to reproduce, I assume that I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas what that might be?

Comment: Didn't find anything about this on releases notes so looks like a good bug candidate,

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will look into submitting an Eclipse bug report. Not too hopeful since I already did this about 3 weeks ago and have not heard a word from them. The process is not intuitive (to me) but I will try again.

Comment: Bug reported to Eclipse. Original bug reported is 581788, submitted April 6, 2023. New bug is 581782.

Comment: Eclipse JDT problems should be reported here - https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues

Comment: Simple hit Ctrl+Shift+O (_Organize Imports_). I agree that a quick fix (Ctrl+1) for that would also be nice. Could you provide a pull request for that?

Comment: Oops. New bug report is 581872, not 581782. You can see it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=581872